# Cant navigate to new user control in wpf from usercontrol view model

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I cannot navigate from one user control to another view.

From view i can navigate by using the following code

```
 <DataGrid.InputBindings>
                <MouseBinding Command="{Binding DataContext.NavCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
            MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick"
           CommandParameter="historyimage"/>
```

Navcommand is the command to navigate the view. Navcommand resides in mainwindowviewmodel. now i have to call that command from another viewmodel.

But i don't know how to redirect from viewmodel.